# Force inherited class to call a base helper method

Tags: c#, oop

I have a base class that contains a helper method. How can I force the inherited class to call this helper method? Is there a way to warn the consumer that GenerateId must be called?Should I make this helper method part of the base constructor logic?

For example:

```
public class FooBar
{
    public int GenerateId(string productCode)
    {
       //..some logic to return an integer;
    }
}
public class AnotherFooBar : FooBar
{
    public void Save()
    {
       var fooBarId = this.GenerateId("myproduct");
       //fooBarId will be used in this code block
    }
}
```

Comment: what's the problem? your code are working fine.

Comment: it depends on **when** do you want to call that method ?

Comment: Anyone that inherits the base class has to call the helper method at least once. Yes, it works fine as it is but it doesn't warn the consumer that they need to call the helper method first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't "enforce" anything on an overriden method. You're looking at this from the wrong perspective.

See [Martin Fowler's Article](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CallSuper.html) about the proper approach to this.

Basically, if your base class needs a specific code executed every time an override is called, then you should only override a "part" of the base method, like so:

```
class A
{
   void MethodOne()
   {
      //Here you perform your obligatory logic.

      //Then, call the overridable logic.
      MethodOneCore();
   }

   virtual void MethodOneCore()
   {
      //Here you perform overridable logic.
   }
}

class B: A
{
   override void MethodOneCore()
   {
      //Here you override the "core" logic, while keeping the obligatory logic intact.
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like this:

```
    public abstract class FooBar
    {
        public void Save()
        {
            var fooBarId = this.GenerateId("myproduct");
            SaveCore(fooBarId);
            //fooBarId will be used in this code block
        }

        protected abstact void SaveCore(int id);
    }
```

The subclass now is enforced to call that method when Save is called. I don't know if the id is then needed by SaveCore if it is you can pass it as a parameter as in the sample.

After that if it's not needed you can make the GenerateId private since it seems by the name it might be not something you want to make people free to do.

Anyway consider to document well what SaveCore and id stands for since inheritance add complexity to your implementation and subclass might be implemented in a wrong way.

Answer (score 3):

You can make the base class abstract and force the deriving classes to implement a method. Place the method which must call `GenerateId()` in the base class and let it call the abstract method:

```
public abstract class FooBar
{
    protected abstract string Product { get; }

    private int GenerateId(string productCode)
    {
       //..some logic to return an integer;
    }

    public void Save()
    {
       var fooBarId = this.GenerateId(Product);
       SaveInternal(fooBarId);
    }

    protected abstract void SaveInternal(int id);
}

public class AnotherFooBar : FooBar
{
    protected override string Product { get { return "myproduct"; } }

    protected override void SaveInternal(int id)
    {
       // id will be used in this code block
    }
}
```

Also, since the deriving classes will probably want to generate IDs for different products, create an abstract readonly `Product` property in the base class as well, thus forcing the deriving classes to supply a product name.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for? (Your question is not totally clear...)

```
public class FooBar
{
    public abstract int GenerateId(string productCode);

    public void Save()
    {
       var fooBarId = this.GenerateId("myproduct");
       //fooBarId will be used in this code block
    }
}
public class AnotherFooBar : FooBar
{
    public override int GenerateId(string productCode)
    {
       //..some logic to return an integer;
    }
}
```

Comment: No, because I don't want the inherited class to implement its own GenerateId. The base class has to do that.

Comment: Ah, I see... then Fabio's and Olivier's answers would do what you're looking for...